# Detached entity passed to persist when child is persisted and the parent already exist Spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

An exception is thrown when i persist a '**Proyecto**' instance. I guess the bidirectional setting is ok, i would appreciatte any help, I guess the problems are related with the cascade types. I have been stuck with this exception for two days.

My related entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "proyecto")
public class Proyecto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false)
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "duracion", nullable = false)
    private Integer duracion;

    @Column(name = "interno", nullable = false)
    private boolean interno;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tutor")
    private Personal tutor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_encargado_externo")
    private PersonalExterno encargadoExterno;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_status")
    private Status status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proyecto", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProyectoEstudiante> proyectoEstudianteSet = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "fecha_creacion")
    private LocalDateTime fechaCreacion;

    @Column(name = "fecha_modificacion")
    private LocalDateTime fechaModificacion;

    public ProyectoEstudiante registerStudent(Estudiante estudiante){
        var proyectoEstudiante = new ProyectoEstudiante(estudiante, this, true);
        this.proyectoEstudianteSet.add(proyectoEstudiante);
        estudiante.getProyectoEstudianteSet().add(proyectoEstudiante);
        return proyectoEstudiante;
    }
// getter and setters
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "estudiante")
public class Estudiante implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "carnet", nullable = false, length = 10)
//  @Size(max = 6, min = 6, message = "Carnet must be a 6 character identifier")
    private String carnet;
    
    @Column(name = "horas_progreso", nullable = true)
    private Integer horasProgreso;
    
    @Column(name = "servicio_completo", nullable = true)
    private boolean servicioCompleto;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "estudiante", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ProyectoEstudiante> proyectoEstudianteSet = new ArrayList<>();

    public Estudiante() {
        super();
    }

    public Estudiante(String carnet, Integer horasProgreso, boolean servicioCompleto){
        this.carnet = carnet;
        this.horasProgreso = horasProgreso;
        this.servicioCompleto = servicioCompleto;
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "proyecto_estudiante"
        , uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = {"carnet", "id_proyecto"}))
public class ProyectoEstudiante implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_proyecto_estudiante")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "carnet")
    private Estudiante estudiante;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_proyecto")
    private Proyecto proyecto;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proyectoEstudiante", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante> estadoRequerimientoEstudiantes = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_proyecto_estudiante", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Certificado certificado;

    @Column(name = "activo")
    private Boolean active;

    public ProyectoEstudiante() {
    }

    public ProyectoEstudiante(Estudiante estudiante, Proyecto proyecto, Boolean active) {
        this.estudiante = estudiante;
        this.proyecto = proyecto;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public void setCertificado(Certificado certificado) {
        this.certificado = certificado;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Estudiante getEstudiante() {
        return estudiante;
    }

    public void setEstudiante(Estudiante estudiante) {
        this.estudiante = estudiante;
    }

    public Proyecto getProyecto() {
        return proyecto;
    }

    public void setProyecto(Proyecto proyecto) {
        this.proyecto = proyecto;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addRequerimiento(Requerimiento requerimiento, boolean aprobado){
        var requerimientoEstudiante = new EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante(this, requerimiento, true,
                aprobado, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), null);
        requerimiento.addEstadoRequerimiento(requerimientoEstudiante);
        this.estadoRequerimientoEstudiantes.add(requerimientoEstudiante);
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "requerimiento")
public class Requerimiento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "original", nullable = false)
    private boolean original;

    @Column(name = "cantidad_copias", nullable = true)
    private Integer cantidadCopias;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_proceso")
    private Proceso proceso;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_documento")
    private Documento documento;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requerimiento", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante> estadoRequerimientoEstudiantes = new HashSet<>();

    public Requerimiento() {
        super();
    }

    public Requerimiento(Integer id, boolean original, Integer cantidadCopias, Documento documento) {
        this.id = id;
        this.original = original;
        this.cantidadCopias = cantidadCopias;
        this.documento = documento;
        documento.getRequerimientos().add(this);

    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "estado_requerimiento_estudiante")
public class EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private EstadoRequerimientoEstudiantePK id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @MapsId("idRequerimiento")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_requerimiento")
    private Requerimiento requerimiento;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @MapsId("idProyectoEstudiante")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_proyecto_estudiante")
    private ProyectoEstudiante proyectoEstudiante;

    @Column(name = "entregado")
    private boolean entregado;

    @Column(name = "aprobado")
    private boolean aprobado;

    @Column(name = "fecha_entrega")
    private Date fechaEntrega;

    @Column(name = "fecha_aprobacion")
    private Date fechaAprobacion;

    public EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante() {
    }

    public EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante(ProyectoEstudiante proyectoEstudiante, Requerimiento requerimiento, boolean entregado, boolean aprobado, Date fechaEntrega, Date fechaAprobacion) {
        this.id = new EstadoRequerimientoEstudiantePK(requerimiento.getId(), proyectoEstudiante.getId());
        this.proyectoEstudiante = proyectoEstudiante;
        this.requerimiento = requerimiento;
        this.entregado = entregado;
        this.aprobado = aprobado;
        this.fechaEntrega = fechaEntrega;
        this.fechaAprobacion = fechaAprobacion;
    }
```

```java
@Embeddable
    public class EstadoRequerimientoEstudiantePK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id_requerimiento")
    private Integer idRequerimiento;

    @Column(name = "id_proyecto_estudiante")
    private Integer idProyectoEstudiante;

    public EstadoRequerimientoEstudiantePK(Integer idRequerimiento, Integer idProyectoEstudiante) {
        this.idRequerimiento = idRequerimiento;
        this.idProyectoEstudiante = idProyectoEstudiante;
    }

    public EstadoRequerimientoEstudiantePK() {

    }
```

The service method i'm testing:

```java
@Override
    public ProyectoCreationDTO.ProyectoDTO save(ProyectoCreationDTO proyecto) {
        try {

            var proyectoToSave = this.proyectoMapper.proyectoCreationDTOToProyecto(proyecto);
            ZoneId zid = ZoneId.of("America/Guatemala");
            proyectoToSave.setFechaCreacion(LocalDateTime.now(zid));
            proyectoToSave.setStatus(entityManager.getReference(Status.class, 1));
            this.setEncargado(proyectoToSave, proyecto.getPersonal());

            proyecto.getEstudiantes().forEach(carnet -> {
                var studentProxy = this.entityManager.getReference(Estudiante.class, carnet);
                var proyectoEstudiante = proyectoToSave.registerStudent(studentProxy);
                this.requerimientoRepository.findAll()
                        .forEach(requerimiento -> {
                            proyectoEstudiante.addRequerimiento(requerimiento, false);
                        });
            });

            
            var savedProyecto = this.proyectoRepository.save(proyectoToSave); // fail on this line 
            return this.proyectoMapper.proyectoToProyectoDTO(savedProyecto, new CycleUtil<>());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new InternalErrorException("Something went wrong saving the data");
        }

    }
```

The integration test:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Profile("test")
public class ProyectoServiceIT {

    @Autowired DocumentoRepository documentoRepository;
    @Autowired  RequerimientoRepository requerimientoRepository;
    @Autowired StatusRepository statusRepository;
    @Autowired  EstudianteRepository estudianteRepository;
    @Autowired ProyectoRepository proyectoRepository;
    @Autowired DepartamentoRepository departamentoRepository;
    @Autowired PersonalRepository personalRepository;
    @Autowired TipoPersonalRepository tipoPersonalRepository;
    @Autowired EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired ProyectoMapper proyectoMapper;


    @Test
    void serviceSave() {
        var service = new ProyectoServiceImpl(proyectoRepository, documentoRepository, proyectoMapper,
                estudianteRepository, requerimientoRepository, entityManager);
        var carnet = "zh15002";
        var status = new Status(1, "Pendiente", "desc");
        var dep = new Departamento(1, "Ing");
        var tipo = new TipoPersonal(1, "Docente", "any");
        var personal = new Personal(1, "chepe", "lastname", dep, tipo);
        personal.setEmail("some.email@gmail.com");
        var doc = new Documento("doc1", "desc", LocalDateTime.now());
        var req1 = new Requerimiento(1, true, 2, doc);

        statusRepository.save(status);
        departamentoRepository.save(dep);
        tipoPersonalRepository.save(tipo);
        personalRepository.save(personal);
        documentoRepository.save(doc);
        requerimientoRepository.save(req1);
        estudianteRepository.save(new Estudiante(carnet, 100, false));
        
        assertEquals(0, proyectoRepository.count());

        var statusDto = new StatusDTO(1, "", "");

        var proyecto = new ProyectoCreationDTO("proyecto", 250, true, 1, List.of(carnet), statusDto);

        service.save(proyecto);
        assertEquals(1, proyectoRepository.count());
        var c = documentoRepository.findProjectRelatedDocuments("zh15002", "proyecto");

        var result = proyectoRepository.findById(1);
        assertTrue(result.isPresent());

        var project = result.get();

        assertEquals(project.getNombre(), proyecto.getNombre());
        assertEquals(project.getDuracion(), 250);
        assertTrue(project.isInterno());

        var requirement = (PendingProjectDTO) service.getRequirementsData(carnet).get(0);
        var docs = requirement.getDocumentos().iterator().next();
        assertEquals(requirement.getNombre(), proyecto.getNombre());
        assertEquals(requirement.getDuracion(), 250);
        assertTrue(requirement.isInterno());
        assertEquals(requirement.getPersonal(), personal.getNombre());
        assertEquals(requirement.getStatus(), status.getStatus());
        assertEquals(docs.getNombre(), doc.getNombre());
    }
}
```

The exception output:

```java
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: ues.occ.proyeccion.social.ws.app.dao.Requerimiento; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ues.occ.proyeccion.social.ws.app.dao.Requerimiento
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.save(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.save(Unknown Source)
    at ues.occ.proyeccion.social.ws.app.service.ProyectoServiceImpl.save(ProyectoServiceImpl.java:155)
    at ues.occ.proyeccion.social.ws.app.service.ProyectoServiceIT.serviceSave(ProyectoServiceIT.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

It seems a problem related with the cascade between '**Requerimiento**' and '**EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante**' entities. I have tried many cascade configs but does not work, and only fails with this test where '**Requerimiento**' objects already exists.

The following test **works** but there's no existing '**Requerimiento**' objects

```java
@DataJpaTest
@Profile("test")
class DocumentoRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired DocumentoRepository documentoRepository;
    @Autowired RequerimientoRepository requerimientoRepository;
    @Autowired EstadoRequerimientoEstudianteRepository requerimientoEstudianteRepository;
    @Autowired EstudianteRepository estudianteRepository;
    @Autowired ProyectoRepository proyectoRepository;
    @Autowired StatusRepository statusRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    void findProjectRelatedDocuments() {
        String projectName = "anything", carnet = "zh15002";
        var status = new Status(1, "Pendiente", "pendiente");
        statusRepository.save(status);

        var documento1 = new Documento("Doc 1", "Test doc 1", LocalDateTime.now());
        var documento2 = new Documento("Doc 2", "Test doc 2", LocalDateTime.now());

        var unsedDocumento = new Documento("unsedDocumento", "Test unsedDocumento", LocalDateTime.now());

        documentoRepository.saveAll(List.of(documento1, documento2, unsedDocumento));

        var requerimiento1 = new Requerimiento(1, true, 2, documento1);
        var requerimiento2 = new Requerimiento(2, true, 3, documento2);

        requerimientoRepository.saveAll(List.of(requerimiento1, requerimiento2));

        var estudiante1 = new Estudiante(carnet, 300, false);
        var estudiante2 = new Estudiante("ab12345", 300, false);

        estudianteRepository.saveAll(List.of(estudiante1, estudiante2));

        var proyecto = new Proyecto(1, projectName, 250, true, LocalDateTime.now());
        proyecto.setStatus(status);

        var proyectoEstudianteResult1 = proyecto.registerStudent(estudiante1);
        var proyectoEstudianteResult2 = proyecto.registerStudent(estudiante2);

        // requerimientos relacionados a estudiante1
        proyectoEstudianteResult1.addRequerimiento(requerimiento1, false);
        proyectoEstudianteResult1.addRequerimiento(requerimiento2, true);

        proyectoEstudianteResult2.addRequerimiento(requerimiento1, false);
        proyectoEstudianteResult2.addRequerimiento(requerimiento2, false);
        // save of this proyect works because there's no existing Requerimiento objects
        proyectoRepository.save(proyecto);  


        var result = documentoRepository.findProjectRelatedDocuments(carnet, "Anything");
        assertEquals(2, result.size());
        // --------------------------
        var requerimientos1 = result.get(0).getRequerimientos();
        var resultRequerimiento1 = getFirstItem(requerimientos1);
        var requerimientoEstudiante1 = resultRequerimiento1.getEstadoRequerimientoEstudiantes();

        var resultRequerimientoEstudianteOptional1 = test(requerimientoEstudiante1, carnet);
        assertTrue(resultRequerimientoEstudianteOptional1.isPresent());
        var resultRequerimientoEstudiante1 = resultRequerimientoEstudianteOptional1.get();

        assertEquals(1, requerimientos1.size());
        assertEquals(resultRequerimiento1.getcantidadCopias(), 2);
        assertFalse(resultRequerimientoEstudiante1.isAprobado());

        // --------------------------
        var requerimientos2 = result.get(1).getRequerimientos();
        var resultRequerimiento2 = getFirstItem(requerimientos2);
        var requerimientoEstudiante2 = resultRequerimiento2.getEstadoRequerimientoEstudiantes();

        var resultRequerimientoEstudianteOptional2 = test(requerimientoEstudiante2, carnet);
        assertTrue(resultRequerimientoEstudianteOptional2.isPresent());
        var resultRequerimientoEstudiante2 = resultRequerimientoEstudianteOptional2.get();

        assertEquals(1, requerimientos2.size());
        assertEquals(resultRequerimiento2.getcantidadCopias(), 3);
        assertTrue(resultRequerimientoEstudiante2.isAprobado());


    }

    private <T> T getFirstItem(Set<T> set){
        var iter = set.iterator();
        return iter.next();
    }
    private Optional<EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante> test(Set<EstadoRequerimientoEstudiante> set, String carnet){
        return set.stream().filter(obj -> obj.getProyectoEstudiante().getEstudiante().getCarnet().equals(carnet)).findFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't read the question carefully, yet I think you need to fetch the existing record to make hibernate aware that it should not insert the related record.

Comment: @Jahan in the service, the statement `this.requerimientoRepository.findAll()` fetch the existing records